# Call function for ng-repeat from directive with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a reusable list-like directive.
Example code is without styling, etc.

The code does invoke the callback but no argument is passed.
Ideally, it would return the object for that row or its index.

- The passed function 'callback' comes from a controller.
- The directive has no controller directly associated to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Directive:

```
module.directive('quicklist', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=ngModel',
            clickFn: '&callback'
        }
        template:'<ul><li ng-repeat="d in data"><a href="" ng-click="clickFn(d)">{{d}}</a></li></ul>'
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<quicklist ng-model='array' callback='work(arg)'><quicklist>
```

Comment: Why do you use inline js in your template? You could use ng-click in there. Just a comment...

Comment: I'm probably being thick but I'm assuming you' re talking about the ' javascript;'  statement. In that case, you're right and I'm being silly. *fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I pass functions to be used with parameters in the directive, i use the `=` binding:

```
scope: {
            data: '=ngModel',
            clickFn: '=callback'
        }
```

And in your HTML just pass the function's name without the argument:

```
<quicklist ng-model='array' callback='work'><quicklist>
```

Comment: I do too and have never quite figured out why there was a need for `&` syntax to pass full function in markup as string....which does also work

Comment: @charlietfl If you figure it out, let me know :)

Comment: Thank you.I was taught to pass functions with '&' .

Comment: @Groulien I see many peple use it too...but passing an object as reference is such a common thing in javascript making the `=` more intuitive ...bit of a mystery to me honestly. Probably an answer for it in one of the style guides somewhere